# PhpStorm 8.0.3 crashing itself and Windows Samba share

Tags: windows-7, centos, phpstorm, samba, windows-explorer

I access the code on my CentOS VM through a Samba share on my Windows machine.

I have been using PhpStorm for a while now, however this morning I have been unable to use PhpStorm to access the Samba share.

When PhpStorm loads it shows a blank screen (no project window) and within 15 seconds locks up and turns black, at the same time it seems to crash the Samba share or at least Windows' ability to access it.

Is this a common problem?

I am using PhpStorm 8.0.3.

Comment: Downgrading back to PhpStorm 8.0.1 seemed to clear this problem, but I still have no idea why this happened so randomly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this was caused by the access to the Samba share being cut off due to my Virtual Machine shutting down and PhpStorm getting confused as to why it can't access it.

As mentioned in the comments above a downgrade to a slightly older version solved the issue in the meantime.